# TeeChart area fill color with gradient strange

Tags: c#, winforms

i have following problem at TeeChart: when gradient and transparency are set to the area chart, the blue fill area looks somehow strange. With vertical lines. How can I make area fill color in one color? Without this vertical lines. Code:

```
        nominalArea.AreaBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(29, 125, 151);

        nominalArea.Gradient.Visible = true;
        nominalArea.Gradient.Transparency = 20;   

        nominalArea.AreaBrush.Gradient.StartColor = nominalArea.AreaBrush.Color;
        nominalArea.AreaBrush.Gradient.EndColor = nominalArea.AreaBrush.Color;
        nominalArea.LinePen.Color = nominalArea.AreaBrush.Color;
```

[image]

Comment: what's happen when your don't use transparency?

Comment: Then is ok, solid color. But I have to use transparency.